# itext pdf generation fail on parsing some html tags

Tags: java, html, pdf, html-parsing, itext

I have this html code, which reside in db and I want to parse it in pdf.
I am using itext for pdf generation. 
here is the html in db:

```
<p>no note.</p><br>
<ul><br>
<li><strong>section</strong></li><br>
</ul><br>
<ol><br>
<li>first</li><br>
<li><em>second</em></li><br>
<li><span style="text-decoration: underline;">third</span></li><br>
</ol><br>
```

and here is what is parsed and inserted into pdf:

```
<p>no note.</p><br>
<strong>section</strong><br>
first<br>
<em>second</em><br>
<span style="text-decoration: underline;">third</span><br>
```

and also here is my code to parse the html into pdf:

```
org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc = Jsoup.parse(text);
List<Element> objects;
objects = HTMLWorker.parseToList(new StringReader(doc.outerHtml()), null);
for (Element object : objects) {
        Element ele = (Element) object;
        document.add(ele);
}
```

as can be seen numbers and bullet are not shown (which are "ol" and "li" tags in html).
How to solve this?

**Edit**

For more clarification. Here is the text I have in html:

[image]

and here is the note inserted into pdf:

[image]

Comment: Note that HTMLWorker has been abandoned in favor of XML Worker. HTMLWorker is no longer supported.

Comment: Yes I know it is deprecated, but I couldn't find an alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my friend just solved it:

`XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(new XHtmlElementHandler(document), new StringReader(text));`

simple :)

Comment: What API / package is that XHtmlElementHandler from? my Ide can't find it. I do have itext and XMLWorker with it. I'm having exactly same issue as you had here, but can't create new XHtmlElementHandler. My Eclipse doesn't suggest anything for it.

Comment: What version of itext do you have?

http://api.itextpdf.com/xml/com/itextpdf/tool/xml/XMLWorkerHelper.html

Comment: Me too, I can't find the `XHtmlElementHandler`; please give us the maven dependency or just the import package...

Comment: http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/xml-worker/xml-worker-examples

Here is the maven repository:

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.itextpdf.tool/xmlworker

Comment: Can't find XHtmlElementHandler :/

Comment: I am having  same problem .I could not find XHtmlElementHandler .I am using xmlWorker 5.4.2 jar.Can anyone help me to find

Answer (score 1):

`HTMLWorker` is deprecated long time ago and its intention was not to convert complete HTML pages. It basically does not know web page consists of `<head>` and `<body>` section.

`XMLWorker` was meant as a generic framework to **parse XML**. To avoid these conflicts, **iText 7** came into play with `convertToPdf` function which is capable of converting HTML into PDF.

Following would be the code snippet.

```
HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(new File(src), new File(dest));
```

Add your HTML coding into first parameter and provide file location to save HTML into PDF in provided location (file path).